# I want to count rows of column between dates

Tags: mysql, sql

Table contains columns `id`, `fid`, `created_date`.

> fid is not present in all rows.

Here is my sql query:

```
select  count(*) fid from users where created_on between '2017-01-06 00:00:000' AND '2017-01-06 23:59:59.997' not in ('');
```

I want to count fid rows between dates, I tried with this query but it is not returning proper output, I am getting total count in result, I want count between  the dates I entered

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select count(*) from users where created_on between '2017-01-06 00:00:00' AND '2017-01-06 23:59:59';
```

Comment: Yes this is perfect but i want to count fid column.

Comment: If fid is a unique id, this will give the count of fid's else you can try 
select count(distinct(fid)) from users where created_on between '2017-01-06 00:00:00' AND '2017-01-06 23:59:59';

Comment: Thank you So much, i got the perfect result :) ;) Have a good dat @nbirla

Comment: @Coderfe : If it helped, please mark it as the answer